# XMLSerialization doesn't set properties on de-serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, ixmlserializable

I have a weird behavior, which I don't even know how to diagnose.

Some properties during de-serialization are not set (null), even though I clearly see them in the (just-produced) XML document. The XML document looks well structured and symmetric with regards to similar types of objects.

It looks like it sets values up to a certain point, then stops setting values and beyond that ignores all other data.

Just to point out - the last value it sets correctly is an object of type that contains another object for which, because of issues of singleton-like de-serialization, I had to implement `IXmlSerializable`. I'm pointing this out since it could hint at some bug, although I can't figure out what it could be.

**EDIT**:
I read [some articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302752/changing-where-xmlserializer-outputs-temporary-assemblies) about retrieving the serialization assembly and code. For some reason, it only outputs the .dll and the .pdb file, but not the .cs, as the articles mention

Thanks

Comment: A code example is worth a zillion words

Comment: @Lochemage, I'd love to, but that would be the entire project. I haven't a clue about how to reduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved! This is a two-part solution:

### 1) Enabling diagnostics

First, in Visual Studio 2012 (or perhaps more correctly in .NET 4.5), it's **not enough** to set the following in the app.config for XmlSerialization diagnostic:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="1" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.xml.serialization>
    <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="c:\foo"/>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

You also need to add the attribute `useLegacySerializerGeneration="true"` to produce the auto-generated .cs file of the serializer

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="1" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.xml.serialization>
    <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="c:\foo" useLegacySerializerGeneration="true"/>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

### 2) Pitfall in IXmlSerializable implementation

Make sure that XmlReader (when it's in the `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` method of `IXmlSerializable`) is on the **StartElement** of the next element when you're done with it, not on the EndElement. In other words, make sure to call:

```
reader.ReadEndElement();
```

Because of it, xml deseralization reader got skewed data and read all the elements in the wrong places, producing nulls.

Comment: This still works as of Visual Studio 2017. Note that when adding `tempFilesLocation`, intellisense will add a squiggly and say "tempFilesLocation attribute is not allowed."  Ignoring this and rebuilding allowed me to debug into the *.cs files.  Also, the `randomname.cs` files that I needed didn't show up in the temp directory until I hit the breakpoint where the deserialization was happening.  After doing this I was able to debug through the code generated via the wsdl and determine the source of the issue.