# C#, .NET 4.5: Unexplained parameter on XMLSerializer constructor overload ("location")

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Working in C# under .NET 4.5.  I have looked through questions here and also performed many Google and MSDN searches, and cannot find any explanation or definition for the "location" parameter of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642407(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of the XMLSerializer constructor. I don't know if it is a namespace, URI, path, etc.  Can anyone tell me what this parameter indicates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, use [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,981f5e32136f3265). `location` is ultimately passed to the constructor of `TempFileCollection` by `XmlSerializerCompilerParameters`. If no value is supplied, one is taken from the configuration file (specifically the `tempFilesLocation` key from the `system.xml.serialization` section), with which we can confirm its true purpose: it's the location for temporary files generated (and read back) by the XML serializer. It's true that the documentation is particularly obtuse on this point.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  I have been doing Microsoft development for a lot of years, and I'm still not used to being able to see the source for anything Microsoft!  I'll do my best to remember that avenue next time before posting questions...

Answer (score 2):

If you follow through the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,292c7197dcb706a1) you end up [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs,661).

It would seem it's the directory that `XmlSerializer` will put the serializer assembly it generates.

If not specified (which is the case with all other overloads), it uses the [`TempFilesLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.configuration.xmlserializersection.tempfileslocation(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be configured [per this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302752/changing-where-xmlserializer-outputs-temporary-assemblies).