# Change XML temp output location from SOAP Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, soap, acumatica

I am trying to change where XmlSerializer Outputs Temporary.  I am using a website (webforms) to connect to a SOAP service (Acumatica accounting system) and for some reason it is trying to write to the IIS path locations:

IIS Express:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express**\files.xml

IIS: 
**c:\windows\system32\inetsrv**\file.xml

I do not want to grant access to these folders. How do change the location of the temp xml file.  I tried this [Changing where XmlSerializer Outputs Temporary Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302752/changing-where-xmlserializer-outputs-temporary-assemblies) but it did not work for me. I should mention that the website runs as IIS_WPG user.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Just got an answer from consultant firm that is helping me with this issue.

Add this line of code to the gobal.asxp file:

`IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory({folder Path here})`

Hope this helps somebody.